Sqlite3.dll in PHP is missing the rtree support for GPKG
I'm using Laragon to develop some code in PHP to read a geopackage file.
Not really sure about the PHP environment, I've manually updated it, downloading the thread safe version from the official repository.
To load the sqlite3 dll I've uncommented the line

extension=sqlite3

And the original dll that comes in the PHP package correctly works. The issue is that I'm getting the error

SQLite3::query(): Unable to prepare statement: 1, no such module: rtree

I found out this means that the sqlite dll provided with php (8.2.25) is missing rtree support.
I tried compiling my own version, to include the rtree support.
I've downloaded the sqlite3 version I needed from the official website (sqlite-amalgamation-3260000), unzipped it in a folder, opened that folder with Visual Studio Community, and compiled with the settings in the attachment, but it's not loading it, giving the error:

Invalid library (maybe not a PHP library) 'sqlite3'

how can I get a precompiled sqlite3 library, compatible with my php version, working in windows, with rtree enabled?
Or, alternatively, how can I compile it myself for PHP?
